# Let function $f=u +iv$ is analytic on $D$ and for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ and $au+bv=c$ on $D$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Let function $f=u +iv$ be analytic on some domain $D$. Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ such that $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ and $au+bv=c$ on $D$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $D$.

What I have done is following: Actually I only thought that Can I use Liouville's Theorem because we already have $f$ is analytic and if it is bounded that would imply that $f$ is constant by Liouville's theorem. But how can I show that $f$ is bounded?

After seeing answer I write these:
We have $au+bv=c$ and C-R equations which are $u_x = u_y$ and $u_y = - v_x$ then we get
\begin{align}
 \label{eq1}
 au_x +b v_x &= 0 \tag{1}
 \\
 \label{eq2}
 au_y + b v_y &= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
If I substitute $u_y$ and $v_y$ with appropiate pairs in \eqref{eq2} then
$$\label{eq3} au_x +b v_x = 0 \tag{3}$$ and $$\label{eq4} -av_x + b u_x = 0\tag{4}$$
Combining these two equations \eqref{eq3},\eqref{eq4},
$$(a+b)u_x + (b-a)v_x = 0 \tag{5}$$

And I stop here. Could help a little more?

Comment: $au+bv = c$ means that all values $f(z)$ are on a *line* in $\Bbb C$. Now use https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181311/42969

Comment: You need to assume that $D$ is connected (at least).

Comment: second hint, in line with Steve's: use CR to sub out all instances of any partials of v. Then attempt to get something in the form of $(a^2 + b^2)______ = 0$. Conclude that _____ is 0, a similar argument will show that f' is 0, which is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  differentiate both sides of $au + bv = c$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.  Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof assuming that $D$ is open & connected.
Note that $\lim_{t \to 0} {f(z+th)-f(z) \over t} = f'(z)h$. Hence
$a \operatorname{re} (f'(z)h ) + b \operatorname{im} (f'(z)h ) = 0$ for all $h$. If $a \neq 0$ choose $h=\overline{f'(z)}$ to get $f'(z) = 0$, and similarly if $a=0$. Hence $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

With the given condition $a^2+b^2\ne 0$, solve $(3)$ and $(4)$ simultaneously to get $u_x=v_x=0$ or equivalently $u_x=0$ and $u_y=0$ (By CR-equations). Now what does it tell about $u(x,y)$? Use Liouville's theorem then.

Comment: I combine $(3)$ and $(4)$ and I got $(a+b)u_x + (b-a)v_x = 0$. How did you obtain $u_x=v_x=0$? Btw, if $u_x = u_y = 0 $ that means $u(x,y)$ is constant.

Comment: @Elise9...See that the determinant of coefficient matrix of $u_x$ and $v_x$ is $a^2+b^2(\ne 0)$ which implies that there is only zero solution viz. $u_x=v_x=0$. This in turn suggests $u=const$.

Comment: @Elise9..Let me know if you still feel difficulty in the understanding of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

notice that $a-ib\neq 0$
$g:=(a-ib)\cdot f -c=i\cdot(av -bu)$ is analytic and purely imaginary hence constant on each connected component.  *Justification:* either open mapping theorem, or max modulus theorem applied to $\exp\circ g$ and examining its derivative.  Conclude $f =\frac{g+c}{a-ib}$ is constant as well.